# How do I pass a float as an argument in my python function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to do a simple function; however, I receive this error: 'float' object is not subscriptable.

I know the float is causing the error, i'm just not sure how to handle this.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
# prediction probabilities
probs = [0.886,0.375,0.174,0.817,0.574,0.319,0.812,0.314,0.098,0.741,
         0.847,0.202,0.31,0.073,0.179,0.917,0.64,0.388,0.116,0.72]

# threshold value
thresh = 0.5

def predict(x,y):
    for i in x:
        if i >= y[0]:
            z.append(1)
        else:
            z.append(0)
            return(z)

predict(probs,thresh)
```

Comment: If `y` is a `float`, what are you expecting `y[0]` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments above, I think you are looking for something like:

```
def predict(x, y):
    z = []
    for i in x:
        if i >= y:
            z.append(1)
        else:
            z.append(0)
    return z
```

The key things to note are 1) creating `z` so that you can append to it 2) not having the `return` call inside the `else` body (or else it returns the very first time you end up in that body and stops going through all the elements of `x`).

Comment: can i ask you another similar question or maybe I should just make another post?  I'm doing another similar list exercise

Comment: @EvanDay You should probably ask a different question.  Part of the idea with Stack Overflow is to create a vast library of questions tied to (ideally) good answers as a resource to folks who end up having similar questions.  So it is best to carefully package up each question as its own thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because `y`, which is `tresh` which is set to `0.5`, a float value.
Did you mean `x[0]`? Because this is a list.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is loop through probs, and if probs is >= to thresh then add 1 to a new list (z)

Comment: @EvanDay the `y[0]` means your code thinks y is list-like and that it will return the first element of that list but y is just equal to the value 0.5--i.e. it is not list-like--so that creates the error.

Comment: @skumhest, yes, i see that now thank you.  I resolved that error but now it looks like i'm not looping through the entire list

Comment: @EvanDay I also noticed that the code hasn't created `z` before it tries to append to it.  Did you resolve that, too?

Comment: 'def predict(x,y):
    for i in x:
        if i >= y:
            z.append(1)
        else:
            z.append(0)
            return(z)'

Comment: @skumhest Yes, I create z before the function, i just didn't include it here.  The only error i'm having now is that my output is just [1,0] which i'm assuming the code is just stoping and not looping through all the values in probs.